# How to ask for PhD position 1 year after previous application

Tags: phd, application

I applied to a good university in the UK last year for a PhD. I was invited for an interview but withdrew my application because I got another position in a different country where my wife was also accepted. Unfortunately, we could not stay there. I did not start in the program. I got a temporary research assistant position two months after graduating, and I should now plan for the future. I would like to ask if the university in the UK would be still interested in taking me as a student. Would it be possible to use my previous recommendation letters they already have? Is this is a horrible idea? What should i write them?

Comment: I can't answer for the UK, as there it may be different - but in the US all the grad programs I know of have explicit policies that say that you must complete the formal graduate application process even if you had applied the previous year. Some don't require test scores to be resent, some do - I think all of them required letters to be resent. I suspect you'll need to ask their graduate program coordinator what they require, with the expectation you'll probably have to submit all (or nearly all) materials again.

Comment: And you should not use existing letters even if they allow it - you want your letter writers to update their letters based on all the awesome things you've been doing in the last year.  Outdated letters carry less weight and sometimes look suspicious, as if something has happened in the last year that you want to conceal.